# Spring Security (4.0.1) Integration with AngularJS. Getting Basic Authentication Popup every time user enters invalid credentials

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, popup, basic-authentication, www-authenticate

I am trying to integrate Spring Security (4.0.1) with AngularJS. I am able to do basic authentication using XML based configuration. The problem is, Web browser displays Pop up every time user enters invalid credentials. I have tried to remove WWW-Authenticate repsone header using plain ServletFilters as well as using Spring security based Custom filters. No success yet. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend default `ExceptionTranslationFilter` that returns an HTTP 401 for all ajax requests instead of a basic authentication challenge:

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter;

public class AjaxExceptionTranslationFilter extends ExceptionTranslationFilter {

    @Autowired
    public AjaxExceptionTranslationFilter(AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
        super(authenticationEntryPoint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void sendStartAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, AuthenticationException reason)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean isAjax = "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));

        if (isAjax) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
        } else {
            super.sendStartAuthentication(request, response, chain, reason);
        }
    }
}
```

Add `AjaxExceptionTranslationFilter` to your configuration right before default `FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR`:

```
<security:http pattern="/**">
    <security:custom-filter before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" ref="exceptionTranslationFilter"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</security:http>

<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="mypackage.AjaxExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
</bean>
```

You'll need to add an interceptor for HTTP header `X-Requested-With` to your ajax calls in your angular app in order to trigger `AjaxExceptionTranslationFilter` in the backend.

Further you should catch an HTTP 401 response from the backend and handle it accordingly.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function($q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if(rejection.status === 401) {
                // .. do something meaningful
            }


            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);

$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function ($q) {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            config.headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
            return config || $q.when(config);
        }
    };
}]);
```

}]);